# as3 loop loading urls - continue loop on complete

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, for-loop

I am trying to load a bunch of files in order. I want the other to start downloading once the previous has downloaded. I thought the best way to do this would be through a for loop.

TheURL = is a bunch of urls in a ARRAY

```
for(var i:int=0;i<TheURL.length;i++)
{
    var urlString:String = TheURL[i];
    var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
    var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();
    var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
    urlStream.load(urlReq);

function loaded(event:Event):void
    {
        /// code to continue loop
    }

}
```

It is important that the others do not start downloading until the previous has completed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function downloadFiles():void
{
    downloadNextFile();
}

function downloadNextFile():void
{
    var urlString:String = TheURL.shift();
    var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
    var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();
    var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
    urlStream.load(urlReq);
}

function loaded(event:Event):void
{
     downloadNextFile();
}
```

Comment: Damn, you were faster :D But didn't you mean `shift()` instead of `unshift()`?

Comment: Awesome! I will test it later today. Don't have time now. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Using a for-loop does not solve what you want to do.

In my opinion the easiest way should be to use the array of URLs as a queue. This can be done by using `Array.shift()`. But you should make a copy of your array if you need the original set of URLs when finished, because `shift()` makes an inline modification of the array.

The solution could be the following:

```
function loadQueue(urlQueue:Array):void
{
    var url:String = urlQueue.shift();
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
    var stream:URLStream = new URLStream();
    var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

    var completeHandler:Function = function(event:Event)
    {
        // remove listener from stream to be a clean coder ;)
        stream.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

        // handle completion in the way you need ...

        // continue with the next element
        if (urlQueue.length > 0)
           loadQueue(urls);
    }

    urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
    urlStream.load(urlReq);
}
```

Loading your queue will then look like:

```
loadQueue(TheURL.concat()); // concat() will clone your array
```

Comment: I need a lil help with this. Have not got it to work yet but I love the concept. Do you have a moment? For example you posted. urlStream.load(urlReq); But in your code urlReg is gone. Am I missing something? Also will this code only "concat" with a comma? My array is separated by "|"  - -loadQueue(TheURL.concat());

Comment: I didn't name the request `urlReq`. In my code it is simply called `request`. In general I didn't copy your code and changed it - I  rewrote it. ;) The array: how can your Array be separated by '|' unless it's a string with '|' as separator? If `TheURL` is such a string, then use `TheUrl.split("|")` that will create an array of strings. When `TheURL` is an array already, then `TheURL.concat()` will simply creates a new array with the same elements of `TheURL` in the same order. [API Doc of Array.concat()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#concat())

Answer (score 0):

You should use a library like greensock LoaderMax http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/.
It's much more difficult than it seems to create your own loading queue. There are plenty of bugs, traps and special cases to deal with. It seems to work fine, and one day a customer call you back because of a bug on this particular flash version on this computer behind this firewall... I've started to do mine library, but finally I used LoadManager.

Comment: Its called LoaderMax, not LoaderManager (I corrected my answer). You can find it there http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/ . Just download it and take some time to learn it before you use it. It's worth it. I've been able to create dynamic queue for browsing a gallery of 20000 images smoothly.